# Migrate MySQL database from Windows 7 to CentOS server

Tags: windows-7, ssh, centos, mysql

I have a Joomla website which I need to migrate from shared hosting to a VPS  having CentOS 7 installed on it.

I have already taken the whole website backup including the database on my Windows 7 machine.

I have tried to create the necessary environment by installing Apache, MySQL, PHP.

I have also created an empty database and the username having the same name as that in the configuration.php file. I really wanted to make the minimum changes to configuration.php file so I kept the database name and username unchanged.

Now, before I could move Joomla folders/files to a new location, I need to have the newly created empty database replaced/restored/populated with the old(backed-up) database file.

I have spent nearly two days looking for a way to do that but could not find anything related to it.

So, how do I access the database on my local windows machine and migrate and restore that database to another server?

I am using Putty as an SSH client to connect to the vps.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` is the standard MySQL backup command-line tool. You can also clone your database to another environment using the files produced by `mysqldump`.

Following the examples from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html
you can backup your source DB with:
`mysqldump --all-databases --master-data --single-transaction > backup_file_*somedate*.sql`
and then restore it to target:
`mysql < backup_file_*somedate*.sql`

Comment: Could you explain HOW to use these tools to accomplish what OP needs?